# Overlaying view on custom view Android

Tags: android, class, view

I am writing a Phonics game for children and I have currently an activity class which uses a custom view class to display the picture of the letter, however I need to implement buttons on the screen also. I was wondering how I would go about placing these buttons on the view class because an XML view would be needed but I am unsure how I would go about this.

PhonicsActivity.java class

```
public class PhonicsActivity extends Activity{

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = new PhonicsView(this);
    setContentView(view);



}
```

PhonicsView.java class

```
public class PhonicsView extends View {

public PhonicsView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    drawLetterA(canvas);

}
```

Basically how would I get buttons on for next letter, previous letter and menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive XML layout elements using

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button)
yourView.addView(button);
```

If you want to do this programmaticly.

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
yourView.addView(button);
```

Comment: Thanks Edward that has helped alot!